# How make a stacked plot on several binary variables in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, ggplot2, statistics

I have been trying to make a stacked barplot on a set of thematic variables:

```
Theme 1 <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,0)
Theme 2 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,2,2,0,1)
Theme 3 <- c(2,2,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
Theme 3 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,0)
```

where: 0 = No, 1 = Yes and 2 = Missing

I want to make a stacked plot of these themes are against different regions in my dataframe, so I can see which regions focus on what themes.

list of regions:

```
Region_abb <- c(ESA, WCA, MENA, ASIA)
```

I have tried making a matrix:

```
Themes_matrix <- matrix(c(Theme 1), nrow = length(Theme 1))

(Themes_matrix_app <- cbind(Themes_matrix, Theme 2, Theme 3, Theme 4))
```

(## But now I am missing Theme 1 as name in my matrix!, how do I get it back?)

```
barplot(Themes_matrix_app, main = "Theme Overview", 
        xlab = "Themes", 
        col=c("darkblue","orange", "red"), #representing the different levels for my theme variables
        legend = rownames(Themes_matrix_app))
```

(##But this doesn't plot the different levels (0,1,2) and everything is in black!)

So I tried:

```
p2 <- ggplot (data = MY_df, aes(Themes_matrix_app, value = Themes_matrix_app, fill = Region_abb))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

(## This just flat out didn't work)

My goal is reaching what was portrayed on: [How to plot an histogram in R with several variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463586/how-to-plot-an-histogram-in-r-with-several-variables)

I have tried coping the coding from the first example, but I just didn't get it.

I hope that my fairly long question makes sense and that someone can help me move on from here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using ggplot2. First to use ggplot your data needs to bee in tidy format (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html). So using the data you provided:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Q = 1:10, Theme1 = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,0),
Theme2 = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,2,2,0,1),
Theme3 = c(2,2,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1),
Theme4 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,0))
tidy_df <- df %>% 
  gather(key = "Theme", value = "Answer", 2:5)
```

Then plotting the data using ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = tidy_df, aes(x = Theme , fill = as.factor(Answer)))+
  geom_bar()
```

[image: stacked bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base r option:

```
out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(list(Theme1,Theme2,Theme3,Theme4),table))
rownames(out) <- c("T1","T2","T3","T4")
barplot(t(out))
```

[image: Beautify to your hearts content]