# Plotting a histogram with two vectors next to each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as follows:

```
A <- structure(c(9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 6, 4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 9, 
8, 8, 9, 5, 5, 8, 7, 5, 9, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 4, 7, 9, 8, 
6, 7, 7, 4, 8, 6, 9, 9, 8, 1, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 6, 7, 4, 7, 9, 
6, 6, 9, 9, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 9, 5, 7, 9, 8, 4, 9, 8, 8, 8, 
5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 5, 9, 6, 9, 6, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
4, 6, 4, 8, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 8, 8, 8, 7, 9, 3, 8, 8, 6, 
9, 8, 8, 6, 5, 8, 3, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 6, 9, 5, 9, 8, 7, 9, 7, 9, 
9, 8, 9, 6, 8, 9, 8, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9, 4, 8, 8, 5, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 
9, 6, 8, 5, 9, 8, 7, 9, 9, 7, 6, 8, 7, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 
6, 6, 9, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 2, 4, 9, 9, 7, 7, 9, 7, 6, 9, 9, 8, 5, 
5), label = NA_character_, class = c("labelled", "numeric"))

B <- structure(c(9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 6, 9, 8, 8, 6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 9, 
7, 8, 9, 7, 9, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 
8, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 4, 8, 9, 
8, 7, 9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 2, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4, 9, 9, 8, 
3, 7, 3, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
7, 3, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 6, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 7, 
8, 9, 9, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 5, 8, 8, 7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 9, 
8, 7, 9, 4, 8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9, 9, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
8, 9, 5, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 
7, 4, 8, 7, 7, 9, 8, 8, 7, 5, 8, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9, 
7), label = NA_character_, class = c("labelled", "numeric"))
```

I figure out how to do this:

```
hist(A, breaks=9, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5), xlim=c(1, 9), xlab = "Personal Norm", main = paste("Distribution of the Personal Norm"))
hist(B, breaks=9,col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5), xlim=c(1, 9), add=T)
legend("topleft", c("tax", "truth"), fill=c(rgb(0,0,1,0.5), rgb(1,0,0,0.5)))
```

But I prefer to have the bars separate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463586/how-to-plot-an-histogram-in-r-with-several-variables) (answer by Len Greski). I posted the code from his answer below. But I cannot figure out how to apply his answer to my data. Can anyone help me?

```
rawData <-                                          
"sector  Year2003    Year2004    Year2005    Year2006    Year2007
Agriculture   532918    543230        532043      562146    585812
Mining        1236807   1258769     1263937      1250930    1235517
Construction 1505948    1598346      1645017     1785796    1874591
Manufacturing 6836256   7098173     7302589      7731867    7844533
Wholesale      8635763  918174       966467       1037362   1070758"

library(reshape2)

gdpData <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE,
                      sep="",stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

gdpMelt <- melt(gdpData,id="sector",
            measure.vars=c("Year2003","Year2004","Year2005","Year2006","Year2007"))

gdpMelt$year <- as.factor(substr(gdpMelt$variable,5,8))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(gdpMelt, aes(sector, value, fill = year)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
     scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: You want the answer using base R plot or `ggplot2` ?

Comment: I think `ggplot2` has my preference, but I would be happy with base as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(value = c(A, B), 
                 variable = rep(c("tax", "truth"), each = length(A)))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(value, fill = variable), position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rgb(0,0,1,0.5), rgb(1,0,0,0.5))) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.1, 0.85))
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you want, consider accepting the answer

Comment: I will ;), Do you know how to make the x-axis display all values instead of quartiles?

Comment: Add `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:9), labels = c(1:9))`!

Answer (score 1):

Rather using `barplot`. Just `table` each column of an A-B data frame and use possible values as `levels=` of a `factor`.

```
tb <- sapply(data.frame(A, B), function(x) table(factor(x, levels=sort(unique(unlist(d))))))
clr <- c(rgb(0,0,1,0.5), rgb(1,0,0,0.5))

b <- barplot(tb, beside=T, col=rep(clr, each=nrow(tb)), xaxt="n")
axis(1, as.vector(b), rep(1:nrow(tb), 2))
legend("topleft", c("tax", "truth"), fill=clr)
```

[image]

Or transposed version:

```
barplot(t(tb), beside=T, col=clr)
legend("topleft", c("tax", "truth"), fill=clr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it also possible to have each number side by side, with this solution?

Comment: @Tom What exactly to you mean by each number side by side?

Comment: Like the answer Leonardo suggested (which works perfectly so it is not absolutely necessary, just out of curiosity).

Comment: @Tom Yes! That's even easier, just `t`ranspose the table (edit).